# Getting the field of a child object from a parent object in criteria query. (Hibernate/Persistence)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have an object (A), that has a field that contains another `object` (B), and B has a field of `long` type. I want to be able to access B's long type field in a criteria query.

In the example code, we see how to get the field of an object, but is there a way to get objectA.objectB.field in a similar way as the example code looks like?

I have found this example code:

```
CriteriaQuery<Integer> criteria = builder.createQuery( Integer.class );
Root<Person> personRoot = criteria.from( Person.class );
criteria.selec(1)t( builder.max( personRoot.get( Person_.age ) ) );
criteria.where( builder.equal( personRoot.get( Person_.eyeColor ), "brown" ) );
Integer maxAge = em.createQuery( criteria ).getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is we can use multiple get functions inside of each.

Example:

```
criteria.where(builder.equal(ParentClass.get("ChildClass").get("FieldOfChildClass"), "value" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create join from the root by specifying the join type

```
Join<ObjectA, ObjectB> objectBJoin = personRoot.join("objectB", JoinType.INNER);
```

Comment: Object A and Object B are not literally separate objects. Object B is a value of one of Object A's field. So I don't see how this does what I asked for.

Comment: You can access a field in the child class by         criteria.where(builder.equal(objectBJoin.get("FieldInObjectB"), "value")